# How to cut a long clip in several clips every 2 seconds in Premiere Pro CC?

Tags: video, adobe, video-editing, adobe-premiere

I have a long video which I am trying to cut in several clips in Premiere CC. I would like to cut each 2 second of the whole clip, therefore making *(x number)* of clips of 2 seconds. This would take ages manually , and would not be exactly 2 seconds for each. I searched for information, but could not find anything. Totally new to this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 2 secs clip and drop it on top of the original clip's layer, copy-paste that 2secs clip repeatedly to the length of original clip, then you just need to hold cut keyboard shortcut (for mine is 'C') and play with mouse cursor until all the original clip has been splited by 2 secs

Comment: ok, I have to say it is meticulous but if that is the way , thanks I will give it a try!